# Convert long number as string in the serialization

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a custom made class that use a long as ID. However, when I call my action using ajax, my ID is truncated and it loses the last 2 numbers because javascript loses precision when dealing with large numbers. My solution would be to give a string to my javascript, but the ID have to stay as a long on the server side.

Is there a way to serialize the property as a string? I'm looking for some kind of attribute.

Controller

```
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
   public IEnumerable<CustomerEntity> Get()
   {
      yield return new CustomerEntity() { ID = 1306270928525862486, Name = "Test" };
   }
}
```

Model

```
public class CustomerEntity
{
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Result

```
[{"Name":"Test","ID":1306270928525862400}]
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You could probably create a custom `JsonConverter` and apply it on your property.

Following is an example (**NOTE**: I haven't used this api before so it could probably be improved more, but following should give you a rough idea):

```
public class Person
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(IdToStringConverter))]
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class IdToStringConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken jt = JValue.ReadFrom(reader);

        return jt.Value<long>();
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(System.Int64).Equals(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Web API Action:

```
public Person Post([FromBody]Person person)
{
    return person;
}
```

Request:

```
POST http://asdfasdf/api/values HTTP/1.1  
Host: servername:9095  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Content-Type: application/json  
Content-Length: 42  

{"ID":"1306270928525862400","Name":"Mike"}
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK  
Content-Length: 42  
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8  
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0  
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 17:02:18 GMT  

{"ID":"1306270928525862400","Name":"Mike"}
```

**EDIT**:
if you do not want to decorate the property with an attribute, you could instead add it to the Converters collection. Example:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new IdToStringConverter());
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great! The only downside of that answer is that our entities are inherited from a custom entity template in our ORM that is used in every project that we have (some of them are not web based). That would imply to add a dependency from Newtonsoft.JSON to the ORM, and every project that we have would need newtonsoft too. I would prefer an attribute that doesn't depend on a DLL.

Comment: @Bruno: one thing to warn you though. This converter would convert all longs to string. You should probably look into ways to do some checks so that it doesn't apply application wide and also any performance enhancements as to not trigger this converter apart from types you expect, like example: `CustomerEntity`

Comment: We rarely use long for something that is not an ID anyway

Comment: Nice solution - it might be worth mentioning that it doesn't handle `long?` (`Nullable<long>`) which sometimes is useful as well.

Comment: Also regarding the 'Edit' - in case someone has the same problem - it didn't want to work for me because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620110/webapi-custom-jsonconverter-not-called

Comment: `value.ToString()` can be localized when `value` is a `long`, so you should format the value using invariant settings, e.g.  `((IConvertible)value).ToString(NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`

Comment: Thanks, It works. I want to convert String to Number type 

https://gist.github.com/najathi/23b7bbba45583f357e5659a5e946d031

Answer (score 2):

How about a `view model` that only has `string` properties, like this:

```
public class CustomerEntityViewModel
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now you are only dealing with `string`s and `JSON` serialization problems go away.

Comment: I think he wants to keep long on server side

Comment: @cinek - He can, because he could convert the `CustomerEntity` model class to the `CustomerEntityViewModel` and pass that down to the client, then when returning to the server it could be converted back to a `CustomerEntity` class and the ID is a `long` again. I agree it is jumping through hoops, but if that precision is necessary, then some conversion to `string` needs to happen somewhere.

Comment: That would imply to make a view model for each of my entities (because they all use a long ID) and duplicate every properties in each of them

Comment: @Bruno - Sadly, yes that is what I am implying. :-(

Comment: @Bruno Perhaps you could refactor your entities and all inherit from a base class that contains the ID, that way if you ever need to make a sweeping change like this again you will only need to change it once.

Comment: The problem with this approach is (in some cases, not talking specifically about this case) that the default value of string is different than int/long/etc'. If these models are being used to make requests to an endpoint that expects a number or zero, but then gets an empty string instead, it might fail or present erratic behavior. This is solvable as well, however it's safer to just create a JSON converter at one place and solve the issue

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just create an anonymous type when I call the json serializer like;

```
 JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { instance.Name, instance.ID.ToString() } );
```

In the case where your class has 20 or something fields and this becomes a very ugly solution I would add a string to the class called `ID`, change the long to `lID` or something and use the serializer settings to ignore the long when serializing so the resulting json will only have the string version.

There are several different attributes that will accomplish this for example;

```
 public class CustomerEntity
 {
      [ScriptIgnore]
      public long _ID { get; set; }
      public string ID { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Will not serialize `_ID`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your case, you could potentially use getters and setters to masquerade the property as a string during JSON serialization.

```
public class Money
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public decimal Money { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("money")]
    public string MoneyAsString
    {
        get { return Money.ToString("0.00"); }
        set { Money = decimal.Parse(value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In new `System.Text.Json` class.

You can use this:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    namespace XXX.Common
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        public class LongToStringConverter : JsonConverter<long>
        {
            public override long Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                return Convert.ToInt64(reader.GetString());
            }

            public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, long value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
            {
                writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

You can use it in `Startup.cs`

```cs
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{    
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new LongToStringConverter());
});
```

For more info,view [How to write custom converters for JSON serialization (marshalling) in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a viable workaround would be to use another type for the ID? You could use a GUID for example. With a GUID you will never run out of bounds and also this will get serialized as a string by default I think.

Comment: I can't change the type, but I'm looking for a way to serialized a long as a string like the GUID