# Serialize long number as string using JsonResult .net framework mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .net framework 4.7 MVC project using the NuGet Newtonsoft as a serializer.
I would like to serialize a long property as a string. I am trying  [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369278/convert-long-number-as-string-in-the-serialization) but I cannot find what happened and does not work properly with the accepted answer.

I have a test endpoint

```
[RoutePrefix("Test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet,Route("Test2")]
        public JsonResult Test2()
        {
            var customer = new Customer
            {
                Id = long.MaxValue,
                Name = "test15"
            };
            return new JsonResult { Data = customer, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
        }
    }
```

Also, I have the class person and a custom converter

```
public class Customer
    {
        [JsonConverter(typeof(Int64JsonConverter))]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Int64JsonConverter : JsonConverter<long>
    {
        public override long ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, long existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            if (reader.Value == null)
                return 0;

            return long.Parse(reader.Value.ToString());
        }
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, long value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            // convert to string instead, javascript number size is smaller than long
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

My first try is to annotate the property with the converter.
The second try is to remove the annotation from the property and set in WebApiConfig my custom converter

```
public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration configuration)
        {

            configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "API Default",
                "api/{controller}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            //configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new Int64JsonConverter(), new Int64NullableJsonConverter() };
            configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64JsonConverter());
        }
    }
```

Also my global asax class is

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64JsonConverter());
            //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64NullableJsonConverter());
        }
    }
```

I try to set the custom formatters with various ways like

```
//1) First try
            //var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
            //json.SerializerSettings.Converters = GetJsonConverters();

        //2)Second try
        //HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64JsonConverter());
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64NullableJsonConverter());

        //3) Third try
        //JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        //{
        //  Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
        //  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
        //  ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        //  Converters = GetJsonConverters()
        //};

        //4) Fourth try
        //HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new Int64JsonConverter(), new Int64NullableJsonConverter() };

        //5) Fifth try
        //var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        //json.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Int64JsonConverter());
```

but always the result is the long property in not converted to string
I get

```
{
    "Id": 9223372036854775807,
    "Name": "test15"
}
```

Comment: What's the expected value?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I expect "Id": "9223372036854775807" because i convert it to string

Comment: ASP.NET MVC doesn't use Json.NET, it uses the ancient JavascriptSerializer. Json.NET is used in Web API. ASP.NET Core started with JSON.NET before switching to System.Text.Json

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but in JsonConverter, JsonReader, JsonWriter, JsonSerializer I have imported these from the NuGet Newtonsoft?
What I don't understand?

Comment: *MVC itself* doesn't use JSON.NET, so any converters you create won't be used. You'll have to use JSON.NET yourself. Check the answers to [Using JSON.NET as the default JSON serializer in ASP.NET MVC 3 - is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7109967/using-json-net-as-the-default-json-serializer-in-asp-net-mvc-3-is-it-possible). If you migrate to ASP.NET Core MVC you won't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

You may implement [ISerializable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable?view=net-5.0) interface in your Customer class to specify how it will be serialized/deserialized

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I prefer something like global settings because we have many classes,but  i am going to check and this solution